# How to Post JSON from AngularJS to C# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json

I am trying to post a simple JSON to C# Controller but I am getting null. I am new to AngularJS.

here is the angularjs code that posts

```
k = "{ 'id': 1,'name': 'A green door','price': 12.50}";

$http.post("/Inventory/PostSO", k)
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.message = response.status;
    },
    function (error, status) {
        $scope.message = error.error;
    });
```

this is the C# code but string data is always null

```
public ContentResult PostSO(string data)
{
    return null;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why do you send a object as string?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all set the request headers.

> Content-Type - application/json

At second controller action parameter is string, it must be a model, because the action descriptor tries to map sended model to C# object, create a simple class, and define all properties like data in your json example.

And try again :)

Answer (score 1):

Add FromBody-Attribute to Action-Parameter:

```
public ContentResult PostSO([FromBody]string data)
{
    return null;
}
```